# Multi Step Form using fieldset

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have my code in HTML and JavaScript that using fieldset to change step form. I want in every fieldset has own form tag, so when i submitted in 1st fieldset it changing to 2nd fieldset

Here's my HTML code

```
<div class="formhandler">
<fieldset>
    1

    <form>
        <input type="text">
        <?php 
            echo form_button('previous', 'Kembali', array('class'=>'previous action-button'));
            echo form_submit('submit', 'Next', array('class'=>'next action-button')); 
        ?>
    </form>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
    2

    <form>
        <input type="text">
        <?php 
            echo form_button('previous', 'Kembali', array('class'=>'previous action-button'));
            echo form_submit('submit', 'Next', array('class'=>'next action-button')); 
        ?>
    </form>
</fieldset>
```

please help me solve this

Comment: edit: i'm using this plugin
http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/jquery-multi-step-form-with-progress-bar

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    /*custom font*/
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);

/*basic reset*/
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

html {
    height: 100%;
    /*Image only BG fallback*/
    background: url('http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/gs.png');
    /*background = gradient + image pattern combo*/
    background: 
        linear-gradient(rgba(196, 102, 0, 0.2), rgba(155, 89, 182, 0.2)), 
        url('http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/gs.png');
}

body {
    font-family: montserrat, arial, verdana;
}
/*form styles*/
.msform {
    width: 400px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}
.msform fieldset {
    background: white;
    border: 0 none;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    padding: 20px 30px;

    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 10%;

    /*stacking fieldsets above each other*/
    position: absolute;
}
/*Hide all except first fieldset*/
.msform:not(:first-of-type) fieldset {
    display: none;
}
/*inputs*/
.msform input, .msform textarea {
    padding: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: montserrat;
    color: #2C3E50;
    font-size: 13px;
}
/*buttons*/
.msform .action-button {
    width: 100px;
    background: #27AE60;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    border: 0 none;
    border-radius: 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    margin: 10px 5px;
}
.msform .action-button:hover, .msform .action-button:focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px white, 0 0 0 3px #27AE60;
}
/*headings*/
.fs-title {
    font-size: 15px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #2C3E50;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.fs-subtitle {
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #666;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
/*progressbar*/
#progressbar {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
    /*CSS counters to number the steps*/
    counter-reset: step;
}
#progressbar li {
    list-style-type: none;
    color: white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 9px;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
#progressbar li:before {
    content: counter(step);
    counter-increment: step;
    width: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    display: block;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #333;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin: 0 auto 5px auto;
}
/*progressbar connectors*/
#progressbar li:after {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background: white;
    position: absolute;
    left: -50%;
    top: 9px;
    z-index: -1; /*put it behind the numbers*/
}
#progressbar li:first-child:after {
    /*connector not needed before the first step*/
    content: none; 
}
/*marking active/completed steps green*/
/*The number of the step and the connector before it = green*/
#progressbar li.active:before,  #progressbar li.active:after{
    background: #27AE60;
    color: white;
}

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- progressbar -->
    <ul id="progressbar">
        <li class="active">Account Setup</li>
        <li>Social Profiles</li>
    </ul>
    <!-- multistep form -->
    <form id="msform1" class="msform">
        <!-- fieldsets -->
        <fieldset>
            <h2 class="fs-title">Create your account</h2>
            <h3 class="fs-subtitle">This is step 1</h3>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="emailAccount" placeholder="Email" />
            <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password" />
            <input type="password" name="cpass" placeholder="Confirm Password" />
            <input type="button" name="submit1" class="submit next action-button" value="Register" />
        </fieldset>
    </form>
    <form id="msform2" class="msform">
        <fieldset>
            <h2 class="fs-title">Welcome <label id="infoEmailAccount"></label></h2>
            <h3 class="fs-subtitle">For complete account, link with social network</h3>
            <input type="text" name="twitter" placeholder="Twitter" />
            <input type="text" name="facebook" placeholder="Facebook" />
            <input type="text" name="gplus" placeholder="Google Plus" />
            <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
            <input type="button" name="submit2" class="submit action-button" value="Complete" />
        </fieldset>
    </form>
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- jQuery easing plugin -->
    <script src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/js/jquery.easing.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script>

    //jQuery time
    var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; //fieldsets
    var left, opacity, scale; //fieldset properties which we will animate
    var animating; //flag to prevent quick multi-click glitches

    var numStep = 1;
    var errStep = false;

    $(".submit").click(function(){
        var statusStep = false;
        switch(numStep) {
            case 1:
                $.ajax({
                    beforeSend: function(){
                        $('#msform1 .loader').show();
                    }
                    , cache: false
                    , type: "POST"
                    , dataType: "json"
                    , url: "include/InsertAjaxAccount.inc.php"
                    , data: $("#msform1").serialize()
                    , success: function(res){
                        if(res.err){
                            errStep = true;
                            console.error('Custom error: ' + res.errMsg);
                        }
                        else{
                            console.info('OK');
                            errStep = false;
                        }
                        $('#msform1 .loader').hide();
                    }
                    , error:function(){
                        errStep = true;
                        console.error('System error');
                        $('#msform1 .loader').hide();
                    }
                });

                break;
            case 2:
                $.ajax({
                    beforeSend: function(){
                        $('#msform2 .loader').show();
                    }
                    , cache: false
                    , type: "POST"
                    , dataType: "json"
                    , url: "include/InsertAjaxSocialNetwork.inc.php"
                    , data: $("#msform2").serialize()
                    , success: function(res){
                        if(res.err){
                            errStep = true;
                            console.error('Custom error: ' + res.errMsg);
                        }
                        else{
                            console.info('OK');
                            errStep = false;
                        }
                        $('#msform1 .loader').hide();
                    }
                    , error:function(){
                        errStep = true;
                        console.error('System error');
                        $('#msform1 .loader').hide();
                    }
                });

                break;
            default:
                console.error('step not recognized: ' + numStep);
        }
        return false;
    });

    $(".next").click(function(){
        console.log('Error: ' + errStep)
        if(animating || errStep) return false;
        animating = true;

        numStep++;

        current_fs = $(this).parent();
        next_fs = $(this).parent().parent().next().children();

        //activate next step on progressbar using the index of next_fs
        $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");

        //show the next fieldset
        next_fs.show(); 
        //hide the current fieldset with style
        current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
            step: function(now, mx) {
                //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
                //1. scale current_fs down to 80%
                scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
                //2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
                left = (now * 50)+"%";
                //3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
                opacity = 1 - now;
                current_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')'});
                next_fs.css({'left': left, 'opacity': opacity});
            }, 
            duration: 800, 
            complete: function(){
                current_fs.hide();
                animating = false;
            }, 
            //this comes from the custom easing plugin
            easing: 'easeInOutBack'
        });

        //FOR EXAMPLE
        document.getElementById('infoEmailAccount').innerText = document.getElementById('emailAccount').value;

        console.log(numStep);
    });

    $(".previous").click(function(){
        console.log('Error: ' + errStep)
        if(animating || errStep) return false;
        animating = true;

        numStep--;

        current_fs = $(this).parent();
        previous_fs = $(this).parent().parent().prev().children();

        //de-activate current step on progressbar
        $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(current_fs)).removeClass("active");

        //show the previous fieldset
        previous_fs.show(); 
        //hide the current fieldset with style
        current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
            step: function(now, mx) {
                //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
                //1. scale previous_fs from 80% to 100%
                scale = 0.8 + (1 - now) * 0.2;
                //2. take current_fs to the right(50%) - from 0%
                left = ((1-now) * 50)+"%";
                //3. increase opacity of previous_fs to 1 as it moves in
                opacity = 1 - now;
                current_fs.css({'left': left});
                previous_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')', 'opacity': opacity});
            }, 
            duration: 800, 
            complete: function(){
                current_fs.hide();
                animating = false;
            }, 
            //this comes from the custom easing plugin
            easing: 'easeInOutBack'
        });

        console.log(numStep);
    });



    </script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: that's working properly! thank you very much, but i have antoher problem, i can't go to previous step, when i clicked previous button nothing happen. Can you solve that?

Comment: i've try to add another fieldset so i have 5 fieldset but it doesn't work. is it working in just 2 fieldset?

Comment: If you need to return to the previous step, you must put the necessary fildsets in the same form. As is my code, you cant return to previous steps.
You can get any value field of any form because it is in the client side.

Answer (score 0):

You can do for each fieldsets call custom ajax request by javascript depending on step, validating this fields on client-side.

Because if you not use ajax, the page will be refresh and you will lose the step.

Comment: can you give an example how to do it?